# Linker Errors Already defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, node.js, debugging, linker-errors

I am making a nodejs addon. I have 5 files in my visual studio project :

```
comm.h/cc, node_main.cc, util.h/cc
```

I link it with a library `node.lib`

node_main.cc has a function :

```
v8::Handle<v8::Value> StartMethod(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    v8::HandleScope scope(args.GetIsolate()); // node_isolate
    int length = args.Length();
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char[]>> argv;
    for(int i=0;i<length;++i) {
        if(args[i]->IsString()) {
            v8::String::Utf8Value str(args[i]);
            const int strLen = ToCStringLen(str);
            if(strLen) {
                std::unique_ptr<char []> data(new char[strLen+1]);
                strcpy_s(data.get(), strLen+1, ToCString(str));
                argv.push_back(std::move(data));
            }
        }
    }
    return scope.Close(v8::Int32::New(MainMethod(argv.size(), &(argv[0]._Myptr))));
}
```

When i build the solution i get following linker errors:

```
1>node.lib(node.exe) : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall v8::Value::IsString(void)const " (?IsString@Value@v8@@QBE_NXZ) already defined in communicator.obj
1>node.lib(node.exe) : error LNK2005: "public: class v8::Local<class v8::Value> __thiscall v8::Arguments::operator[](int)const " (??AArguments@v8@@QBE?AV?$Local@VValue@v8@@@1@H@Z) already defined in communicator.obj
1>node.lib(node.exe) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall v8::Arguments::Length(void)const " (?Length@Arguments@v8@@QBEHXZ) already defined in communicator.obj
1>node.lib(node.exe) : error LNK2005: "public: class v8::Isolate * __thiscall v8::Arguments::GetIsolate(void)const " (?GetIsolate@Arguments@v8@@QBEPAVIsolate@2@XZ) already defined in communicator.obj
```

The function `IsString(), Arguments::[] and GetIsolate()` is used only in `hello.cc` and `Arguments::Length()` are used in `communicator.cc`. Even then all errors refer to `communicator.cc`.

I am only calling the functions in cc files not giving any new definition.

What is the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you including one .cc file in another?

Comment: @john No i am not includeing .cc file anywhere in my project.

Comment: Perhap you are defining these functions in a header file and not saying that they are inline? There's only a few things that can cause this error but without being able to see all your code and see how your projects are setup it's very hard to say what the problem is. Whatever it is it's nothing complciated, just some basic error in how you wrote the code or created your projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, I found a solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/onA0S01INtw).
Put an #include <node.h> before every #include <v8.h>.